# What is the name for the principle that multiple flexible lines between two points are geometrically equivalent to only one line?

Tags: terminology, architecture

I mentioned this idea to an architect and he immediately seemed to recognize it, but no amount of googling will tell me the name of it.

Comment: what is this "flexible line" concept?  A line is defined as being straight & one-dimensional, which means it can only go in one direction.

Comment: Your description is extremely vague. What do you mean by lines?  Are you talking about the concept of a *two-force member* by chance? Are you talking about drain pipes or ventilation or something like that?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a physical construction concept? Or a mathematical one like how a donut and mug are topologically equivalent? By "flexible" do you mean a single line that can change? Or do you mean multiple versions of a line that span the points?

Comment: You need to edit your question for clarity. Please give an example of what you mean. It sounds to me like you might mean something like three ropes tied to point A, and to point B, all taut  If so, please state that in your question, if not, please use that as a guide to state what you mean in your question.